# Moving from Aldon to another version control product

Tags: version-control, ibm-midrange

We are looking at alternatives to our current Aldon setup for version control. We have both iSeries developers and Windows based developers utilizing Aldon.

One big question I have is how would we move the version control repository from the iSeries to a different source control repository like Github or TFVC? Is it even possible? Or, are we faced with having an old version control repository and a new version control repository?

Part of this problem is our company still uses the iSeries and so I am sure those developers would  still have to use Aldon. Or is there an alternative whereby both iSeries and Windows based developers can utilize the same source control product just not based on the iSeries?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I would like to hear how a github repo can work with libraries,source members, service programs, ... on the ibm i.

Comment: This question is really beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  That said, there are certainly ways to import source control history from one system to another.  The details of that are entirely dependent on the from and to systems though.

Comment: In reference to @StephenRichter, most Git setups on the IBM i move the source code to the IFS to manage from there.  I know of at least one vendor that has seemingly ported Git to work with standard IBM i libraries, source members, etc but I have not tried it yet.  I see no reason it couldn't be done though.

Comment: @StephenRichter - to amplify what Player1st said: IBM added the option to compile RPG directly from IFS stream files quite a while ago, and relatively recently added the same for ILE CL (CRTCLMOD and CRTBNDCL commands). So IBM seems to be moving in the direction of ultimately supporting an all-stream-file source scheme. If your project consists of mostly PASE stuff, with some RPG and CL purely for back-end functionality (no display files, etc.), you can already be there.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that change control, on IBM i, isn't JUST about source code.

Objects need to be built, authorities & attributes need to be retained, data in the database needs to be manged, and you might need to deploy to both local and remote systems.

You can develop scripts to automate a lot of that for you, but it's a lot of work.

A purpose built change control system takes care of that for you.

Full disclosure: I work for a IBM i change control vendor (not Aldon).

Comment: The idea of objects being built and so forth is not unique to IBM i. I wouldn't say "change control" is only about source code on other platforms. It's just that other platforms, particularly Unix and its descendants, tend to have a more "separate tools for separate jobs" approach, and they decouple *source version control* from the build system (and may employ yet another tool to glue them together). This has advantages and disadvantages over a more unified approach. You don't have to write your own build system for other platforms; there are ready-made options out there.

Comment: True, but IBM i objects have some characteristics that other platforms don't have and the 'traditional' change control systems (and build systems) don't support.